# Parse git history and pattern match over it, once a match is found, capture in a variable a value nearby

Tags: regex, git, awk, sed, grep

I have a long git history and I want to find the first instance of  "build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import" and then capture its associated GitOrigin-RevId "d7b349b6b6db24047ae32a1618dd5f5544864225" in a variable.

I have a really hacky, ugly way of doing it and I'm hoping for a cleaner way. This is the correct but hacky and ugly bash cmd that does the job (it doesn't remove the GitOriginRevId part though):

```
sed -e '/build(mariadbstuff)/,/GitOriginRevId/!d' <(git log) > outputfile.txt && sed -n 11p outputfile.txt
```

---

```
... // more contents of git history
 
build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import
    
    Squashed commit of the following:
    
    commit d8829cc7df7a6813f93d224916b10e7c148950be
    Author: Copybara <blah-tools@blah.com>
    Date:   Fri Jul 10 10:26:41 2020 -0400
    
        Project import generated by Copybara.
    
        GitOrigin-RevId: d7b349b6b6db24047ae32a1618dd5f5544864225

... // more contents of git history
```

Comment: Is this a commit message or code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This solution exits Input_file ASAP it gets get id needed by OP and will NOT read whole Input_file which will be faster than reading whole Input_file solution.

```
awk '
/build\(mariadbstuff\): Copybara/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && /GitOrigin-RevId:/{
  print $NF
  exit
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
/build\(mariadbstuff\): Copybara/{       ##Checking condition if a line contains string build\(mariadbstuff\): Copybara escaping ( and ) in it to treat it as literal character here.
  found=1                                ##Setting found variable to 1 here.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && /GitOrigin-RevId:/{             ##Checking condition if found is SET and line has string GitOrigin-RevId: then do following.
  print $NF                              ##Printing last column of current line here.
  exit                                   ##exiting from program from here to save sometime :)
}
'  Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your efficient solution and detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

If we are assuming you always want 11 lines of output, you could use grep:

```
grep -m1 -A11 'build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import' <(git log)
```

From `grep --help`:

```
-m, --max-count=NUM       stop after NUM matches
-A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
```

If we always want to stop at `GitOrigin-RevId`, then grep still works, but I don't think it is any less hacky than what you are already doing:

```
grep -m1 -A20 'build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import' <(git log) \
    | | grep -m1 -B20 'GitOrigin-RevId'
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, This will get you the GitOrigin-RevId line and use awk to get the actual id:

```
revid=$(grep -m1 -A20 'build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import' <(git log) \
    | grep -m1 'GitOrigin-RevId' \
    | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I just need the associated GitOrigin-RevId in a variable, everything else is not needed

Answer (score 1):

`git log` has built in search functions which will be faster than using an external search tool. Use `git log --grep` to show only commit messages which match. It will show the whole message. Search that for `GitOrigin-RevId` using `grep`.

```
git log --grep='build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import' | grep GitOrigin-RevId
        GitOrigin-RevId: d7b349b6b6db24047ae32a1618dd5f5544864225
```

---

But if this is a one off, use your [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). Assuming it is [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix))...

Run `git log`.

Hit `/` to enter search mode.

Type (or paste) `build(mariadbstuff): Copybara import` and hit return.

It will jump to the first match.

Hit `/` to enter search mode again.

Type `GitOrigin-RevId` and hit return.

`/` searches forward from the current location, so it will jump to the associated `GitOrigin-RevId`.